# Resubscription prevention mechanism

Tags: typescript, rxjs, observable

I'm very new to rxjs and fairly new to TS, so there's probably something obvious I'm missing.

**Given**:

- I have a `listener$: Subject<any>` field in my class.
- I have an `api` service field in my class.
- every time `api.someMethod()` is invoked, it returns an Observable I want to subscribe to
- due to some particular reasons**, the code might invoke `.subscribe(this.listener$)` on the same Observable several times, effectively causing a resubscription.
- as a result, the same API response will trigger the same subscriber twice.

**Required**:

I'm trying to find a way to detect and prevent resubscriptions.

So far I tried to implement a custom Observable class that the API methods could return instead. It would track all the calls to subscribe, cache all unique subscribers and prevent a new subscription if the subscriber is already listening. It's a very poor implementation, hence the ask for help.

```
export class MonitoredSubject<T> extends Subject<T> {
  readonly logger = LoggingFactory.get(this);

  constructor(private topic: string, private handlers: Map<any, MonitoredSubscription>) {
    super();
  }

  subscribe(observerOrNext?: PartialObserver<T>,
            error?: (error: any) => void,
            complete?: () => void): Subscription {
    if (this.handlers.has(observerOrNext)) {
      this.logger.warn(this.topic, 'repeated subscription');
      return this.handlers.get(observerOrNext);
    } else {
      this.logger.info(this.topic, 'subscription');
      const superSub = super.subscribe(observerOrNext, error, complete);
      const sub = new MonitoredSubscription(superSub, () => this.handlers.delete(observerOrNext));
      this.handlers.set(observerOrNext, sub);
      return sub;
    }
  }

}


export class MonitoredSubscription extends Subscription {
  onUnsub: Runnable;

  constructor(private sub: Subscription, onUnsub?: Runnable) {
    super();
    this.onUnsub = onUnsub;
  }


  add(teardown: TeardownLogic): Subscription {
    return this.sub.add(teardown);
  }

  remove(subscription: Subscription) {
    this.sub.remove(subscription);
  }

  unsubscribe() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
    if (this.onUnsub) {
      this.onUnsub();
    }
  }
}
```

Problem is, this code does not compile - it looks like `super.subscribe()` is what the compiler doesn't like. Must be smth about TS I don't yet understand.

** the *particular reasons* is the contract of the API service. Its methods return an Observable. Everything would be OK if the API client always was an HTTP client, but I have several implementations, one of which is WebSocket, meaning the same subscription must be valid for however messages will be sent from the API. I want to preserve the contract, i.e. the user of the API must be ignorant of the API implementation details.

Comment: IMO, you're presenting a [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). It would serve you better to present the actual issue instead of presenting the solution you've attempted.

Comment: It looks like the core problem is to mask the real implementation of request-response mechanism, which in you case can use either http requests or websockets. Is my understanding right?

Comment: @picci Yes. That's the initial problem. If it were a single impl (HTTP), Observables would be short-lived and only survive until the response is received. With websockets there can be multiple "responses" and I need them all to hit the same subscriber. No matter how many times the request was sent (and .subscribe() called). pipe(take(1)) is NOT what I want as the API might send multiple "responses".

Comment: I am still struggling to understand the scenario. With http I imagine a simple case: users clicks a button, a request is created (i.e. an Observable mapping the request is created), the request is sent (i.e. the Observable is subscribed) and the response is received (i.e. the function passed into the `subscribe` is executed with the data received). How would such scenario work with websockets? Is the scenario you are facing completely different?

Comment: @Picci With all the respect, I am not asking to solve the design problem. Just the resubscription one.   
To answer your question, the interactor, when received events from the API boundary, be it HTTP or WS, signals the presenter to update its views accordingly. Regardless whether it's a single event (HTTP response) or multiple events (websocket messages with changed state). With HTTP there will be a single update of the view. With WS there will be as many updates as events (messages) are received.
However, the interactor is ignorant of the underlying implementation of the API boundary.

Comment: I hope I have understood the problem and provided you a response which represents a way to address it.

Comment: @MichaelD How come every time I try to elaborate on my qn with some context I'm blamed for presenting an XY problem, and when I omit the context I'm told my qn is too vague? :) NO, this is not an XY problem. I want to castrate the Subject.subscribe() in order to implement Flyweight pattern and solve the problem provided in the footnote.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the problem right, you have an **interactor** that calls an API to send a request and update its view (or model) based on the notifications received over an Observable.

The communication mechanism behind the Observable can be either standard http calls or websocket.

So, if this is right, I would approach the problem like this

First we code the http implementation of the API as a method of a class. We will see later why a class and not a simple function

```
class HttpService {
   sendRequest(params: any) {
      // use an http client whose post method returns an Observable
      return someHttpClient.post(`http://my-url`, params)
   }
}
```

The interactor will use the API like this

```
const service = new HttpService();
service.sendRequest({prop1: val1, prop2: val2, ...})
.subscribe({
   next: response => {
      // update the state with the response
      updateState(response)
   }
})
```

The websocket implementation of the same API will be in a different class but there will be additional complexity to make it work.

First of all I would define a couple of functions which provide an Observable interface to the websocket client, something like this

```
function openSocket(url: string) {
  return new Observable((subscriber: Subscriber<WebSocket>): TeardownLogic => {
    const conn = new WebSocket(url);
    conn.onopen = () => {
      subscriber.next(conn);
    };
    conn.onerror = (err) => {
      subscriber.error(err);
    };
    conn.onclose = (_ev) => {
      subscriber.complete();
    };
  });
}

function messages(socket: WebSocket) {
  return new Observable(
    (subscriber: Subscriber<MessageEvent>): TeardownLogic => {
      socket.onmessage = (msg: MessageEvent) => {
        subscriber.next(msg);
      };
      socket.onerror = (err) => {
        subscriber.error(err);
      };
      socket.onclose = (_ev) => {
        subscriber.complete();
      };
    }
  );
}
```

Then we start the implementation of the websocket service class

```
class WebsocketService {
   // first a Websocket needs to be open and we better store the connection
   // to avoid the handshake for any request. In other words we want to use
   // the same connection for more than one request
   // So we need to define a variable in the class to store the connection
   private socket: WebSocket;

   // then we need to connect the websocket - one way could be to start the
   // connection from within the constructor (there are maybe better solutions
   // but this one seems the simplest to explain)
   constructor() {
     // we use the openSocket function and subscribe to the Observable returned
     openSocket('ws://my-url:8080/....').subscribe({
       // we store the webSocket created in the private variable to be reused
       next: webSocket => this.socket = webSocket
     })
   }
   
   sendRequest(params: any) {
      // the request is sent as a message over the websocket channel
      // using the websocket connection created in the constructor
      this.socket.send(params)
      // then to maintain the same API as in the http case, it return an
      // Observable which will notify all the messaged received
      // In a real implementation you probably want to cache this Observable with
      // a class variable, but this would complicate things
      return  messages(this.socket)
   }
}
```

Now the **interactor** can use the websocket API in the same way as the http one, i.e. like this

```
const service = new WebsocketService();
service.sendRequest({prop1: val1, prop2: val2, ...})
.subscribe({
   next: response => {
      // update the state with the response - in this case there may be more 
      // than one message received over the websocket as response to one message
      // sent
      updateState(response)
   }
})
```

You have to notice though that the above implementation has one potential leak problem which is given that there is no place where the subscription is unsubscribed.

In the http case this is not a problem since an http Observable `complete`s after it has received the response (or `error`s).

With websocket though the Observable does not complete and so we need to understand, in the specific context of the application, how to perform an `unsubscribe` operation or force the Observable to complete. But, again, the right mechanism depends on the specificities of the application.

Comment: Why not just call unsubscribe always? There is no harm unsubscribving from the http call and there is advantages to calling this on the websocket (as you mentioned)

Comment: @Liam the problem is when to unsubscribe. In the simple scenario of the click of a button triggering the request, when can you safely assume that the stream of responses from the websocket server is completed for that particular request?

Comment: I am heavily utilizing websocket's multiplexing feature. And the traffic is quite heavy too (text data, binary data (audio/video/files); both ways). I'm already pushing it, I'm worried adding more subscribers and filters dropping >95% of messages hitting them would make the app unusable. That is why I wanted to leverage the Flyweight pattern by overriding Subject.subscribe() and only creating new subscriptions if it's not a REsubscription; and returning existing identical subscriptions otherwise.